# How to exit with keys like "ESC" or "CANC" from for loop?

Tags: python, operator

I was wondering if there was a simple way to get out of a "for loop" in case it gets too long. I was thinking in a keyboard type input as the interface during this cycle is completely freezed.
Currently I have this cycle inside a function called by an operator.
Example

```
class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
   """call my function"""
    bl_idname = "call.function"
    bl_label = "My Ops"
    def execute(self,context):

        myfunction(self,context)

        return{'FINISHED'}

def myfunction(self,context)
    for many in context.scene:
        many.###blah blah blah
        ###I would like to use the 'Esc' button to exit this cycle
```

Comment: Depends on how you enter in the for-loop. In your case, it will be difficult to make it stop since the `keyboard event` is not given concurrently in your loop. The loop won't catch any new event unless you use some async method.

Comment: @Hikariztw Hi, thanks for the time dedicated to me, I'd like to know something about it, I grope in the dark and I don't know what kind of research to do to find the solution

Comment: I don't really do that before but usually the key input is deal in `def modal(self, context, event):`. This block catch all user `event` which can be determined whether the function should stop or not.

Comment: But as I said, I am aware that the for-loop couldn't get other information in the same time since it is one-thread program. Those event should go after the for loop. So check `asyncio` and `concurrency` and `parallelism` for details.

Comment: I admit I don't understand much, but I have a problem, the modal operator I saw that happens inside a class, the problem is that the function with inside the "for loop" is callable by some operators , so I really don't know how to organize it

Comment: As you might know, Blender comes with python templates as part of the *Text Editor*. Have a look into *Python > Templates > Operator Modal* - In this template `ESC` is already pre-defined and ready to go @Pastrokkio

Comment: @Hikariztw think I think your first comment is correct, I just tested the modal method, but it doesn't detect any input, I tried a while method, until the cycle ends the blender interface is completely freezed